# How do I implement multiple methods of an abstract class efficiently?

Tags: java, oop

I need to implement an abstract class with 3 abstract methods

```
class Example {
    abstract boolean func1();
    abstract boolean func2();
    abstract boolean func3();
}

Example createExample(String option1, String option2, , String option2) {
    if (option1=="something") {
        define func1 in some way
    } else {
        define func1 in some other way;
    }

    depending on option2 hash out the logic for func2;

    depending on option3 hash out the logic for func3;
    
    create and return class Example with the definitions of func1, func2 and func3;
}
```

How do I implement this efficiently?

Comment: What did you try and what is wrong with what you tried?

Comment: Solution 1: Geometric explosion: Create separate code for every combincation
Solution2: Use FunctionalInterface

Comment: Can you show the FunctionalInterface solution? I guess it's similar to @philipp's answer below. What did you think was wrong with that?

Comment: I guess that is the best we can do

Comment: The alternative is to have 3 different interfaces. Which might be closer to the Interface Segregation Principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Supplier<Boolean>` instances, you could do:

```
Example createExample(String option1, 
                      String option2, 
                      String option3) {
    
    // you most likely don't want to use `==` and 
    // instead `.equals(...)` and a `null` check (prior)
    final Supplier<Boolean> f1 = option1 == "something" ? () -> true : () -> false;
    final Supplier<Boolean> f2 = option2 == "something" ? () -> true : () -> false;
    final Supplier<Boolean> f3 = option3 == "something" ? () -> true : () -> false;
    
    return new Example() {
        boolean func1() { return f1.get(); }
        boolean func2() { return f2.get(); }
        boolean func3() { return f3.get(); }
    };
}
```